# How to Deal With Persistent Abuse

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

I honestly have no idea what to do here.. somebody keeps making stack accounts to spam stars in chat and post offensive answers to random JS room peoples questions. It's all spam "tell kittens I love him" or even worse.. a reference to his [obvious censorship of the male reproductive organ].

Do we need a moderator to help us here or do we simply have to flag this user over and over for the rest of our lives? Because I will not keep up with trolls.

Any help here would be LOVELY. I don't even know what to title this question.. lol

Comment: keep flagging.. bans will kick in

Comment: Probably "How to deal with persistent abuse"

Comment: @OGHaza I shouldn't have to keep flagging. That's a waste of my time to keep up with a troll.

Comment: Can confirm. Not only with messages a few of us have had *suspicious* voting going on. http://i.stack.imgur.com/pbWlZ.png notice the times. Other users has seen this exact same pattern in the same time period.

Comment: @RUJordan "keep flagging" is the usual response to ordinary spammers (baba, sports spam, skin care...) as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak I haven't seen any skin care spam. But if they go to hair care I might be screwed -- I'm a sucker for good hair.

Comment: I know I saw quite a few just today which I marked valid. All about saying hi to kittens and other things about kittens. Usually it's hard to tell without context when you aren't in the room. But it was pretty obvious the ones I saw today. I got your back jack.

Comment: He actually posted in more than the three rooms, but I figured seeing the same message three times in the flag queue would get the point home. so far 4? accounts have been created to ask about someones manhood.

Comment: here is an example of two accounts on one question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23920231/829835 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/23920157/829835

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see a specific pattern, use an "other" flag to explain the details or write a mail to team@stackexchange.com. There are a few additional things the SE team can do if someone is trying to circumvent the usual mechanisms and abusing the site.

In general, spam/offensive flags are the way to go. They automatically deleted posts or messages, and for the main site (not chat) they'll also feed into a network-wide spam defense mechanism that will block those users even if they use different accounts.

Comment: So what about when multiple accounts comes into play? Can the spam defense block that?

Comment: @RUJordan Yes, it is not based on accounts. I won't provide any further details though as I only know the rough overview SE has told us mods, and not any details, and I'm not sure which parts that I know are public and which are not.

Comment: Yup; this! And just for the record, @RUJordan, we (moderators) get just as frustrated as you sometimes with some of the very persistent trolls. But recently there are some really cool algos being used which start to hobble these people significantly - in some cases even before moderators get involved. We can't go into details on that, of course... but I've seen them work well. Of course, 'enterprising' trolls can find ways around those things, but it becomes increasingly difficult for them as they go.

Comment: @AndrewBarber that's great news to hear. BradLarson actually came to the JS room and helped us out a great deal, while even lightening the mood a bit. It was well handled and very much appreciated.

Comment: @MadScientist My guess would be ["your IP will be banned without hesitation"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19806/228314), though that would be harsh. Maybe banned in a way that makes SE read-only for you? Not trying to prod, just bringing attention to something already publicized. **Edit:** on second thought, maybe with a *little* hesitation.